# add app on facebook fanpage with facebook sdk C#

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk, facebook-page

someone knows how to do this using the facebook C # sdk, I have an application that the user can add it on your fan page for your control panel on my website, how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try anything so far or shell we give you a complete solution?

Comment: I tried to edit the whole last sentence but I still don't get the meaning. You have an application that user can add on his fanpage that can control his website page?

Comment: Well, it´s quite hard to distinguish what should happen to whom here. Who is "user" and who is "you" and "me" in contrast to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not matter which server language you are using for your App, the process of adding an App to a Page is the same and explained very well in the Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs

Comment: check out the link i posted. you need to follow the tutorial.